# How to open Alacritty in Nautilus when selecting "Open in Terminal"

Tags: command-line, nautilus

I have Alacritty as the default terminal emulator. This means when I press on `Ctrl+Alt+T`, Alacritty opens up. However, when I am inside a certain folder in Nautilus and I right click and select "Open in Terminal", the Gnome terminal opens instead. So how do I change it to Alacritty? I'm on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the nautilus extension [nautilus-open-any-terminal](https://github.com/Stunkymonkey/nautilus-open-any-terminal). That extension adds a right-click menu to open the terminal of your choice in the current directory. Once this new right-click menu is in place, you can remove the original menu by uninstalling `nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal`

Comment: Thanks this worked. I found this site better than the github page for this extension.
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/07/open-folder-in-terminal-ubuntu-plugin